# pydbus throwing error in raspbian lite

Tags: raspbian-stretch, bluetooth, raspbian-buster, dbus

I have successfully installed and used `pydbus` to communicate and control a few Bluetooth LE devices from a Raspberry Pi (full version).

When I tried to do the same with Raspbian lite, I got:

`object does not export any interfaces; you might need to pass object path as the 2nd argument for get()'`

Which I don't get how this has occurred. Am i missing something in the Raspbian lite?

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly because the `pi` user's privileges are different on the full version than they are on a Lite installation.

For example, user `pi` on a Desktop RPi system is able to start and control the default Bluetooth controller using `bluetoothctl`, but not on a RPi Lite system.

For example, are you seeing no controller if you use `bluetoothctl`?

```
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
No default controller available
```

The solution seems to be to add user `pi` to group `bluetooth`:

```
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
```

This should resolve the `bluetoothctl` and `pydbus` issue.

Comment: As always, thanks again for your quick help! I was also wondering, whenever i do apt-get upgrade, it seems the Bluetooth connection reliability was not consistent and in most cases unable to make connection to BLE devices. What was causing this? Or have you faced it before?

Comment: Another question, will this apply in RPi Zero W as well?